# How to import constant fields

Tags: java

I want to import my constants which are in package consts and in class Constants. There I have inside classes.

For example I want to use form `Capability.DEVICE_NAME` instead of `Constants.Capability.DEVICE_NAME`

```
public class Constants {
    public class Capability{
        public final static String DEVICE_NAME = "deviceName";
        public final static String PLATFORM_NAME = "platformName";
        public final static String PLATFORM_VERSION = "platformVersion";
        public final static String APP_PACKAGE = "appPackage";
        public final static String APP_ACTIVITY = "appActivity";
    }
}
```

It have to be in inside classes!

Thank in advance.

Comment: String myString = Constants.Capability.DEVICE_NAME; the rest 'll show itself

Comment: @Stultuske what's the point of that comment?

Comment: @f1sh if he wants it without the Constants, he can do said line and start from there. if he changes the import statements where he uses it, he'll get there. Or he should consider not to use nested classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "start there"? The ``Constants.Capability.DEVICE_NAME`` you suggested is exactly what he is using right now. He wants a shortcut to that constant.

Answer (score 10):

You will have to import your class like below

```
import packageName.Constants.Capability;
```

You can use as you want like below:

```
System.out.println(Capability.DEVICE_NAME);
```

Or You can make your class static and import as below.

```
import static com.Constants.*;
```

Answer (score 7):

This `import packagename.Constants.*;` should work.

Or you can make the nested class static

```
public class Constants {
    public static class Capability{
        public final static String DEVICE_NAME = "deviceName";
        public final static String PLATFORM_NAME = "platformName";
        public final static String PLATFORM_VERSION = "platformVersion";
        public final static String APP_PACKAGE = "appPackage";
        public final static String APP_ACTIVITY = "appActivity";
    }
}
```

and import static:

```
import static packagename.Constants.*;
```